# How to install CentOS 7 into a directory (without booting an install system)?

Tags: centos, system-installation

I have a Linux system and I wish to install CentOS 7 alongside it. The problem is that I cannot boot from an install medium.

Can I install CentOS without the installation system, or start the installation system from a different Linux?

Installing `grub` won't be the biggest issue, it is already there and I can hand-edit a new entry.  Problem is the file system entry creation and installation (think Arch install).

Comment: I don't know much about CentOS tho but Debian/Ubuntu has `debootstrap` for that, Arch has something similar with `pacstrap` maybe this gives you a direction.

Comment: VMs can usually boot into anything.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Thanks, that may be a way, will try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes** you can Install a system without installation media. An installer basically generates binary files, drivers and configurations depending on your hardware and copy them into a partition. As you've issue with installer you can copy all files from a installed system to a partition where you want to install CentOS.

Freshly install CentOS to an approximately similar hardware as **Minimal Installation**. **Don't** update the newly installed system. Keep the freshly installed machine on. Create a new partition in destination system and temporarily mount it in `/mnt/new` folder. Copy all contents of `/` partition of fresh installation with `rsync` to the new partition where you want to install CentOS. Use `-avz` flag with `rsync` as **root** user. **Exclude** `proc`, `/dev`, `/sys`, `/run` directory with `--exclude` with `rsync`.

```
sudo rsync -avz root@newsystem:/* /mnt/new/ --exclude '/dev' --exclude '/proc' --exclude '/sys' --exclude '/run'
```

Now create those excluded directories in new system.

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/new/sys /mnt/new/dev /mnt/new/proc /mnt/new/run
```

Now edit `/etc/fstab` and mount file-system properly. Make proper grub entry and boot the system with newly copied CentOS. If the system unfortunately leave you in `dracut` shell use the command `blkid` to find `UUID` of partitions. Identify `UUID` of your new root partition. Reboot to previously running system and edit `/etc/fstab` with UUID instead `/dev/sda1` etc.

If still it's leaving in `dracut` shell boot the system with `rescue kernel` and rescue `initramfs` and regenerate `initramfs` for your hardware. Now it shall work.

You may install fresh CentOS inside virtualbox on the running system and copy CPU configuration etc. from host. Then copy that installation to desired partition in host.

Most issues occurs while transferring a Linux installation is with display driver and `fstab` entry. So **Transfer a minimal installation** only. Latter install `X Server` and `Gnome` etc.

Comment: Sorry for the late accept, couldn't test earlier!