# Boot time has drastically increased after restoring partition

Tags: partition, restore, gnome-disks

I have made a backup of my Linux  Mint Xfce partition and I have restored it (all with "Disks" - `gnome-disks`) twice. (More [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/406319/32012)). The partition includes all the system (no separate partitions between `/`, `/home/`, `/boot` etc, just `/`.)

After each restoration the system works fine, but the boot time is very long (2-3 minutes) compared to what it used to be (20 seconds maximum).

Why is that and can I fix it?

As I shut down every day I am thinking about reinstalling my system but I would prefer to avoid that, as it would be what the whole backup process was trying to avoid.

---

Update:

I have found a similar situation when shrinking a system partition with a similar system. The situation improved when the same partition was increased back to its initial size. Possibly the system is looking for a "familiar" size of the partition at boot-up and asks for more boot time when it encounters a smaller size...

Comment: When shrinking a partition, did you also shrink the filesystem within it? If you didn't, the discrepancy would probably be noticed in the boot-time quick filesystem check, and it would probably trigger a more in-depth checking which might explain the slow-down. Of course, this won't apply if you used a tool that will automatically handle both filesystem and partition shrinking as a single operation, but you should be aware that not all tools will do that.

Comment: @telcoM - Considering what I said in the "Update": I used `gparted` in order to get space for a new partition on which to test another Linux system. After testing I have deleted that new system and its new partition and increased the one under discussion to its initial size. - As for the initial question: given the above now I think maybe the boot time increase was not related to backup-restoration procedures but to partition shrinking, as I had shrunk the partition that was backed-up&restored . - But now I am in the "Update" scenario, not in that of the restored partition and system.